# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error while trying to get the count

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have `Corporates`  and `EmployeeEvaluations` EF classes. I am performing a Left outer join and when I use the LINQ statement to get the `count` I am getting the following error even though I am checking for null  :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
 CompanyBO result = new CompanyBO();
            try
            {
                using (CompEntities db = new CompEntities())
                var res = await(from c in db.Corporates                                                   
                 join ee in db.EmployeeEvaluations on esj.Id equals 
                 ee.EmployeeId into eels
                 from eelsj in eels.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new { corp = c,  empEvals = eelsj }
                  ).ToListAsync();

result.Qualified = res.Where(a => a.empEvals.EvaluationStatusId != null).Count(a => a.empEvals.EvaluationStatusId == 3);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this condition in your `Where` method:

```
result.Qualified = res.Where(a => a.empEvals != null).Count(a => a.empEvals.EvaluationStatusId == 3);
```

The problem is if `eels` is empty then you will get a `null` value in the `empEvals`, that's why you need to check if that property in your anonymous type is `null` or not in your last query,